# What's the minimum transit time to be legally allowed to enter Singapore?

Tags: immigration, travel, singapore

I [read](https://qr.ae/pKbl01) (sic):

> Singapore immigration law suggests one should have atleast 10 hrs of transit time to get into the Country. [Author: [Nakulan Ramamirthan](https://www.quora.com/profile/Nakulan-Ramamirthan)]

I can't find the legal source of that claim. What's the minimum transit time to be legally allowed to enter Singapore?

Comment: I think that the source isn't saying that this is a legal requirement, it is saying that due to rigorous immigration laws for Singapore, it often takes 10 hours to clear customers (which is also a function of how busy the ports of entry are and how well staffed those ports of entry are at customs stations). I do not believe that the intent is to establish any specific minimum or maximum time.

Comment: @ohwilleke this article describes someone describing departure immigration controls during a systems outage as "super long queues," whereafter her mother had to wait in line for 15 minutes.  I seriously doubt that it takes anything close to 10 hours for a passenger to clear both inbound and outbound customs and immigration controls: https://www.channelnewsasia.com/singapore/changi-airport-terminal-checkpoint-delays-ong-queue-slowness-clearance-delays-ica-3387526

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the real issue is a non-legal issue.

Comment: I think there is a valid legal question in this.  The wording could be improved, but it is reasonable to presume that a layover or unscheduled delay exceeding ___ hours might enable or enact some sort of "right" for a transiting passenger to clear customs and seek more comfortable accommodations for rest and sanitation outside the security of the airport.

Comment: @MichaelHall The question isn't asking about the maximum time, it is asking about the minimum time, presumably under the impression that the Singapore immigration law has a sort of quasi-quarantine. But this seems to be based upon a misreading of the source.

Comment: @MichaelHall it's possible, but in this case I think the more likely explanation is that the person who posted this information on the other site doesn't actually know very much about Singaporean immigration law and has come to this conclusion (at best) because of an incorrect interpretation of a situation where someone was denied entry while trying to transit.

Comment: @ohwilleke, I may have misinterpreted the OP's intent, but minimum vs maximum is confusing the issue.  I said "*exceeding*", as in "if the traveler's delay *exceeds* 10 hours, they are entitled to seek a hotel room..."  (Hypothetically)

Comment: @phoog, I don't see how the scenario in your comment conflicts with mine.  It is reasonable to presume that nations are *not* required to disembark and clear transitory passengers just because they might want to leave the airport for a quick lunch.  But at some point it becomes unreasonable to detain them...

Comment: @MichaelHall Your concern would be a fair one to ask, I just don't believe that this is the actual question.

Comment: @ohwilleke, I don't know how else to interpret the question, and I still don't understand your calling me out over minimum vs maximum.  I'm not confused about that; i.e. if the minimum was 10 hours, and you had a 3 hour travel delay, you would be below the minimum transit time to legally enter Singapore and would be required to remain within the airport.  A 12 hour delay would be above the hypothetical minimum, and you could enter.  How are you interpreting the question?

Comment: The situation I envision is somebody goes to immigration and says they intend to leave on an onward flight departing in 1 hour. There is a good chance that the person would miss their flight, and the agent would rightly advise to stay within the transit area. If they insisted it could be evidence that they did not intend to depart the country as they claim. If you want to enter Singapore and do something and get back, probably 5-6 hours layover is the absolute minimum.

Comment: @user71659, Unless I am miscommunicating, we are on the same page.  I just don't know what that number is...

Comment: @MichaelHall there's no particular conflict; I just have the sense that this question is not appropriate for [Law.SE] because it's asking about a statement  made by someone who has no apparent expertise in law and who did not explain the reasoning behind the statement. There's no reason to think that the statement is accurate. I didn't see anything obviously relevant in Singapore's immigration law or regulations. [Travel.SE] might be a better source of information; people with experience transiting through Singapore are more likely to know how the law is actually applied.

Comment: @phoog, "*it's asking about a statement made by someone who has no apparent expertise in law and who did not explain the reasoning behind the statement.*" Right, which is precisely why most people come to a law Q&A site; to ask those who DO have some expertise in law.  How does that make it not appropriate? I agree that Travel SE might yield a useful answer, but the question specifically asks about being "legally allowed" to enter, not what seasoned travelers may have personally experienced. Might there be an immigration law, or international traveler's bill of rights that is applicable?

Comment: @MichaelHall at its core it's asking for a justification of an incorrect statement (or, rather, one that seems likely to be incorrect).
We have no idea why this guy made tbe statement; there's no way to know why he thinks it's true; saying "I don't see anything relevant in Singapore's immigration law" is not satisfying because it doesn't address the original claim.  Worse, he doesn't actually claim that it's illegal but only that the law "suggests" such a limit.  It's just too vague to be a good question for this site.

Comment: @phoog, I agree that "*immigration law suggests*" is a poor claim to make, and the place to clarify such a statement should be Quora.  But, it is completely on-topic to ask here about what the law actually says.  (i.e. the legal source, or "justification")  Your personal dissatisfaction with "*I don't see anything relevant in Singapore's immigration law*" as an answer doesn't justify a close vote.